# Unable to install django-toolkit with a python virtualenv

Tags: python, django, heroku, virtualenv

I'm relatively new to Python, Django and Heroku. I'm attempting to follow the instructions on setting up a Django Heroku project found [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django). I'm getting stuck at the following command:

```
$ pip install django-toolbelt
```

I get the following error

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django-toolbelt in c:\
django\contactmanager\venv\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in c:\django\co
ntactmanager\venv\lib\site-packages (from django-toolbelt)
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2 (from django-toolbelt)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package psycopg2

Downloading/unpacking gunicorn (from django-toolbelt)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package gunicorn

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory
 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory
 'docs'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory
 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory
 'tests'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory
 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found under directory
 'examples'
Downloading/unpacking dj-database-url (from django-toolbelt)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dj-database-url

Downloading/unpacking dj-static (from django-toolbelt)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package dj-static

Downloading/unpacking static (from dj-static->django-toolbelt)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package static

Downloading/unpacking pystache (from static->dj-static->django-toolbelt)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pystache
    pystache: using: version '0.6' of <module 'setuptools' from 'C:\Django\conta
ctmanager\venv\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.egg\setuptools\__init__
.pyc'>

Installing collected packages: psycopg2, gunicorn, dj-database-url, dj-static, s
tatic, pystache
  Running setup.py install for psycopg2
    building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\build\psycopg2\setup.py", line 568, in
 <module>
        ext_modules=ext)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.34-py
2.7.egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 53, in run
        return _install.run(self)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 337, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 446, in build_
extensions
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\build\psycopg2\setup.py", line 284, in
 build_extension
        build_ext.build_extension(self, extension)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 496, in build_
extension
        depends=ext.depends)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile
        self.initialize()
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize

        vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)
      File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcva
rsall
        raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))
    ValueError: [u'path']
    Complete output from command C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\Scripts\python.ex
e -c "import setuptools;__file__='C:\\Django\\contactmanager\\venv\\build\\psyco
pg2\\setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file_
_, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-ka3mfj-record\i
nstall-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers C:\Djang
o\contactmanager\venv\include\site\python2.7:
    running install

running build

running build_py

running build_ext

building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\build\psycopg2\setup.py", line 568, in <mo
dule>

    ext_modules=ext)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.34-py2.7.
egg\setuptools\command\install.py", line 53, in run

    return _install.run(self)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 563, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 127, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 326, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 337, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 446, in build_exte
nsions

    self.build_extension(ext)

  File "C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\build\psycopg2\setup.py", line 284, in bui
ld_extension

    build_ext.build_extension(self, extension)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 496, in build_exte
nsion

    depends=ext.depends)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 473, in compile

    self.initialize()

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 383, in initialize

    vc_env = query_vcvarsall(VERSION, plat_spec)

  File "C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\msvc9compiler.py", line 299, in query_vcvarsal
l

    raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: [u'path']

----------------------------------------
Command C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\Scripts\python.exe -c "import setuptools;_
_file__='C:\\Django\\contactmanager\\venv\\build\\psycopg2\\setup.py';exec(compi
le(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --re
cord c:\users\hp\appdata\local\temp\pip-ka3mfj-record\install-record.txt --singl
e-version-externally-managed --install-headers C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\inc
lude\site\python2.7 failed with error code 1 in C:\Django\contactmanager\venv\bu
ild\psycopg2
Storing complete log in C:\Users\hp\pip\pip.log
```

According to this [link](http://iambusychangingtheworld.blogspot.in/2013/10/django-to-install-django-toolbelt.html) I'm supposed to install `python-dev`, `python-psycopg2`, `libpq-dev` before installing `django-toolbelt`.

I'm on a Windows machine. How can I install these dependencies? I tried installing them with pip but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently `psycopg2` installers do not work under a virtualenv environment. I downloaded an executable binary from http://stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

To install the native binary in a virtual envrionment, use easy_install:

```
C:\virtualenv\Scripts\> activate.bat
(virtualenv) C:\virtualenv\Scripts\> easy_install psycopg2-2.5.win32-py2.7-pg9.2.4-release.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

This blog post seems useful for your case:

http://www.swarley.me.uk/blog/2014/02/24/create-a-django-development-environment-on-64-bit-windows-for-heroku-deployment/

Or you can just find the windows ports for these dependency packages.